# Scala: Class with traits whose constructor takes another class with a parallel set of traits?

Tags: scala, class, constructor, multiple-inheritance, traits

Suppose I have a class A with a set of mix-in traits, and a class B that has a value of class A. Is there a way for class B to have a set of mix-in traits that require A to have certain traits in turn (including traits extending B that inherit from multiple other such traits)?

Example:

```
trait A
trait Ax extends A
trait Ay extends A

class B(val a: A)               // Should be traits,
class Bx(ax: Ax) extends B(ax)  // but traits can't
class By(ay: Ay) extends B(ay)  // take parameters

class Bxy extends Bx with By    // Can't mix in classes
```

Is there any way to have a Bxy that both inherits from Bx and By and requires a value of A with traits Ax and Ay?

Edit -- Here's an alternate (still non-working) example that may be a bit clearer:

```
class A
trait Ax extends A { def doAx: String = "Ax method" }
trait Ay extends A { def doAy: String = "Ay method" }

class B(val a: A)

trait Bx extends B {
  require(a.isInstanceOf[Ax])
  def doBx: String = a.doAx    // Ax methods not actually accessible here
}

trait By extends B {
  require(a.isInstanceOf[Ay])
  def doBy: String = a.doAy    // Nor Ay methods here
}

class Bxy(a: A with Ax with Ay) extends B(a) with Bx with By {
  def doBxy: String = a.doAx + a.doAy
}
```

Comment: Why would you need it?

Comment: If you want to add functionality to B that requires its instance of A to have certain functionality in turn.

Comment: Bxy would still only take one parameter, and would only hold one A value. I don't want to choose between the Ax and the Ay versions of A, I want to require an A with both traits together.

Comment: Bx and By wouldn't be adding values to the class -- just adding restrictions to the single parameter that gets passed to the class B constructor. (I added an alternate example to clarify that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate this with traits and companion objects with `apply` methods.

```
trait A
trait Ax extends A { def doAx = "Ax method" }
trait Ay extends A { def doAy = "Ay method" }

trait B {
    val a: A
}

object B {
    def apply(aa: A): B = new B {
        val a = aa
    }
}

trait Bx extends B {
  val a: Ax
  def doBx = a.doAx
}

object Bx {
    def apply(ax: Ax): B = new Bx {
        val a: Ax = ax
    }
}

trait By extends B {
  val a: Ay
  def doBy = a.doAy
}

object By {
    def apply(ay: Ay): B = new B {
        val a: Ay = ay
    }
}

class Bxy(val a: Ax with Ay) extends Bx with By {
  def doBxy = a.doAx + a.doAy
}
```

Companion objects `B`, `Bx` and `By` will serve as factories for their companion traits, creating them anonymously.

```
val a = new A {}
val ax = new Ax {}
val ay = new Ay {}
val axy = new Ax with Ay {}

scala> B(a)                       
res0: B = B$$anon$2@62f4ad6f      

scala> Bx(ax)                     
res1: B = Bx$$anon$1@1436dd6f     

scala> By(ay)                     
res2: B = By$$anon$3@6e84ee94     

scala> new Bxy(axy)               
res5: Bxy = Bxy@480101a7          

scala> res5.doBxy                 
res6: String = Ax methodAy method
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't fit code in comment to clarify, but given the following, what'd you want to happen to the `a` variable?

```
trait A
trait Ax extends A
trait Ay extends A

trait B {
  val a: A
}

trait Bx extends B {
  val x: Ax
}

trait By extends B {
  val y: Ay
}

class Bxy(ax: Ax, ay: Ay) extends Bx with By {
  val a = ??? // what do you want `a` to become here?
  val x = ax
  val y = ay
}
```

#### Overriding `a` with different types

```
trait A
trait Ax extends A
trait Ay extends A

trait B {
  val a: A
}

trait Bx extends B {
  val a: Ax
}

trait By extends B {
  val a: Ay
}
```

Then:

```
class Bxy(ax: Ax, ay: Ay) extends Bx with By {
  val a = ay
}
```

is not possible because `ay` isn't `Ax`. Likewise, `val a = ax` isn't possible because `ax` isn't `Ay`.

Comment: The intent of Bx and By isn't to add new A values to B, but to constrain the type of the original a value.

Comment: See 2nd part of answer, where I explain why that is not possible.

Comment: But I don’t want `class Bxy(ax: Ax, ay: Ay)`, I want `class Bxy(axy: Ax with Ay)` -- which should work with Bx and By because axy is both Ax and Ay.

Comment: What would the type of `Ax with Ay` be?

Comment: A = Fruit, Ax = Banana, Ay = Orange, how do we "Banana with Orange" into a single thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can make `B` a trait, abstract class, or take a generic `A`. Here's an example where `B` is a trait:

```
class A
trait Ax extends A { def doAx: String = "Ax method" }
trait Ay extends A { def doAy: String = "Ay method" }

trait B {
  val a: A
}

trait Bx extends B {
  val a: Ax
  def doBx: String = a.doAx
}

trait By extends B {
  val a: Ay
  def doBy: String = a.doAy
}

class Bxy(val a: Ax with Ay) extends Bx with By {
  def doBxy: String = a.doAx + a.doAy
}
```